# If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $n\times m$ matrix such that $AB=I$, prove that rank$(B)=m$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

> If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $n\times m$ matrix such that $AB=I$, prove that rank$(B)=m$.

I am not sure where to begin with this proof. I have that rank$(AB) = m$, but I can't find anything to help me get further. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: If $\mathrm{rank}(B)\lt m$, one can find a vector $v\ne0$ so that $Bv=0$.

Answer (score 4):

We can see the matrix $B$ as a linear transformation

$$B:\Bbb R^m\to \Bbb R^n,\quad x\mapsto Bx$$
and recall a famous and simple result from the basic set theory:

> If $f\circ g$ is injective then $g$ is injective

so from the hypothesis $AB=I$ we get that $B$ is injective and then by the rank-nullity theorem

$$\operatorname{rank}(B)=\dim\Bbb R^m=m$$

Answer (score 3):

We know that rank($B$) $\leq m$.

Also, $m=$ rank($AB$) $\leq$ rank($B$) $\leq m$. (See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)))

So, rank($B$) $= m$

Comment: how can I use rank(B)<=m to imply that rank(B)=m ?

Comment: @Trent: did you also notice he has $m\le\mathrm{rank}(B)$? I think the $\le$ is a typo; it should be $=$.

Comment: @Trent: The chain of the inequalities gives $m \leq rank(B) \leq m$, so we must have equality.

Comment: How can you say rank(AB)<=rank(B)? I thought the formula was rank(AB)<=min(rankA,rankB)

Comment: or wait is that just because there are m columns?

Comment: @Trent: min(rank A, rank B) is definitely $\leq$ rank(B).

Comment: how can we say rank(AB)<=rank(B)? I thought the only thing we could say was that rank(AB)<=rank(A),rank(B)

Comment: awesome I got it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

**An other way using the robjohn hint in comments above:**

By rank theorem, we have:  $\text{rank}(B)+\dim (\ker B)=m$

$X \in \ker(B) \Rightarrow BX=0 $ and $BX=0 \Rightarrow (AB) X=0$ . Since $AB=I$ we have $\ker B=\{0\}$ then $\text{rank}(B)=m$