# If $AB = I$, the identity matrix prove $\mathrm{rank}(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ be an $n \times m$ matrix. Show that if $AB = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, then $\mathrm{rank}(B) = m$.

I'm not exactly sure how to start this problem. I know that rank is related to the RREF of a matrix but I'm unsure as to how I can relate that to this problem..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $n\times m$ matrix such that $AB=I$, prove that rank$(B)=m$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964424/if-a-is-an-m-times-n-matrix-and-b-is-an-n-times-m-matrix-such-that-ab-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rank(AB) <= min( Rank(A), Rank(B) ).  If rank(B) were not $m$ then Rank(AB) would be less than m, but the rank of $I$ is m.  So this would be a contradiction.

Note: here I'm assuming that $m<n$.

Comment: You don't need to assume $m \lt n$.  Your argument is $m=$ Rank$(AB) \le $ Rank$(B)$, but also Rank$(B) \le m$ by counting the columns of $B$.

Comment: @hardmath , thank you.  You're totally right.

Answer (score 2):

Let $L_A, L_B$ the associated linear transformation of each matrix. So $L_AL_B=\text{id}$, from here follows that $L_B$ is injective, i.e., $\ker( L_B)=\ker{B}=\{0\}$. So  $m=\text{rank}{B}+\text{dim}(kerB)=\text{rank}{B}$.